# using undefined variable in python

Tags: python, variables

This code properly flags an error:

```
print "Value b and tab: ", b,"\t-"
b=1
print "Value b and tab: ", b,"\t-"

.

NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

But using this code, where the comma was forgotten before the tab, does not do the same:

```
print "Value b and tab: ", b"\t-"
b=1
print "Value b and tab: ", b"\t-"
```

What is python thinking, when it sees `b"\t-"`? And why doesn't it print out the value of b even when it is assigned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`b'...'` is a *byte string literal* in Python 3.

In Python 2 that is an alias for a regular string, for forwards compatibility with Python 3. See the Python 2.6 *What's New* document, specifically the [PEP 3112: Byte Literals](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals) section:

> Python 3.0 adopts Unicode as the language’s fundamental string type and denotes 8-bit literals differently, either as `b'string'` or using a bytes constructor. For future compatibility, Python 2.6 adds `bytes` as a synonym for the `str` type, and it also supports the `b''` notation.

and the [*String literals*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) section in the lexical analysis chapter of the Python reference documentation:

> A prefix of `'b'` or `'B'` is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is automatically converted with 2to3).

Because in Python 2 the syntax creates a regular Python string, echoing the value afterwards shows the normal string syntax, without the `b` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because `b` before a string literal is interpreted as a command to interpret the string as a *byte* string. So `b'...'` is very different from a raw string literal `'...'`.

This is very common, and is not restricted to just 'b':

- `r'...'` is interpreted as a *raw* string.
- `u'...'` is interpreted as a Unicode string.

and so on.

Basically, try to avoid prepending characters to Python characters as they may change your data types completely.